# Remove or Replace, which one is better when I remove a substring from a string?

Tags: c#, string

I need to remove all occurrences of a sub-string from a string. I could use `Remove()` or `Replace()`, Which one is better?

Comment: if you have to replace all, i would use replace("searchstring", string.Empty)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to remove all occurrences of a substring from a string.

Given that you need to remove **all** occurrences, `Replace` will definitely be a better choice.  `Remove` would require multiple calls, finding the location each time (to pass the appropriate index and length to remove), which means you'd create many temporary strings.  This will just take more work and put extra work on the garbage collector to clean up the temporary strings you'd generate.

Answer (score 2):

`Remove` doesn't remove all instances of a specific substring (unless, of course, you do the work of finding all of the indexes first). Only `Replace` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove will need to get the index of the string to be removed and will remove only one occurrence each time, while replace will need to know just the string to be replaced, so in means of writing it Replace is simpler:

```
string foo = "bar";
string result;
result = foo.Remove(foo.IndexOf("a"));//you will have to repeat that for each instance
```

or

```
string foo = "bar";
string result;
result = foo.Replace("a","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace() is used to replace all occurrences of a string. Remove() can be thought of a backwards Substring() where you discard the string passed and keep the rest.

Comment: With `Remove`, no string is passed. One passes a start index (integer) and optionally a length (integer) of the part to remove.